# How to obtain hyperplane equation between two Convex in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I've wrote a code in MATLAB which asks a user to enter some classes of points in 2D as input(user enter points graphically). When all the points were received, then my code make a Convex Hull of each class and shows them to the user(you can see one example in below image).
[image]

Now my code check these Convex Hulls for any intersection and If two classes was separated from each other(have no intersection), I want to find the Hyperplane equation between this two separated Convex Hulls.

Is there any MATLAB's way to find this *Hyperplane equation*?

I know that Support Vector Machine(SVM) use hyperplane to classify separate classes, but I don't need to train a SVM because I know that my code try to find hyperplane just when two classes are separated. So **I don't want** to use SVM to protect run time of my algorithm from wasting time to computing so many things that I don't need to (one example of using SVM for this, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549714/hyperplane-in-svm-classifier) and this is not my answer!).

Notice: I'm using MATLAB 2014a. I have the coordinate of each point. Best hyperplane is the goal(with maximum margin) and if there is more than one, one of the best hyperplanes is enough. In this part, I just want a hyperplane between two(not more) classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperplane in SVM classifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549714/hyperplane-in-svm-classifier)